# Conditional formatting of one cell based on the value of another

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a cell that I need to format based on the value in another cell.

In the conditional formatting I have rules that I have applied, but only the first and last work, what am I doing wrong with the middle 2?

These are the rules that I have applied;

1) =('Data Input'!$BD$262<35.81)   format cell red
2) ="AND(('Data Input'!$BD$262>35.9,('Data Input'!$BD$262<37.1)"   format cell yellow
3) ="AND(('Data Input'!$BD$262>37.2,('Data Input'!$BD$262<38.5)"   format cell green
4) =('Data Input'!$BD$262>38.5)    format cell blue

Help :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes in your AND formulae.  Also, there seems to be some bracket misalignments going on.  Try:

> 1) =('Data Input'!$BD$262<35.81) format cell red
>  
>   2) =AND(('Data Input'!$BD$262>35.9),('Data Input'!$BD$262<37.1)) format cell yellow
>   3) =AND(('Data Input'!$BD$262>37.2),('Data Input'!$BD$262<38.5)) format cell green 
>   4) =('Data Input'!$BD$262>38.5) format cell blue

Comment: Brilliant.... I couldn't see the wood for the trees... thanks for the speedy response too.